# передать данные из js в новый html?

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли к 2 html подключить 1 js? Хочу чтобы при работе на 1 html при нажатии на кнопку происходила отрисовка дом дерева во 2 html и уже потом переход на 2 html с уже отрисованным деревом?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду. Вы хотите скриптом из одной вкладки исправить содержимое другой вкладки? Или у вас загружается страница, а потом вы подгружаете отдельные куски `html`? Так же не плохо бы предоставить эти `html` файлы. И ваши попытки реализации. В противном случае, вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Нарисовать DOM до открытия нельзя. JS будет работать только после скачивание HTML и самого JS с сервера

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли к 2 html подключить 1 js?

разумеется.

> Хочу чтобы при работе на 1 html при нажатии на кнопку происходила отрисовка дом дерева во 2 html

если понимать буквально, вам надо управлять 2ым html из 1го. точь в точь такое можно сделать воткнув 2й html внутрь 1го с помощью `<iframe>` например.

> при нажатии на кнопку происходила отрисовка дом дерева во 2 html и уже потом переход на 2 html **с уже отрисованным деревом?**

т.е. по сути все что вам нужно, это бесшовный переход с одной полноценно отрисованой страницы, на другую полноценно отрисованую(без недогруженных элементов) пусть даже и ценой задержки? грубо говоря это реализуется с помощью xmlHttpRequest и ~innerHTML.

+обязательно почитайте про ajax, json и html шаблоны в JS.